# Visa for France from Italy - expired permesso

Tags: france, italy

I am currently residing in Italy and my permit stay is expired. I am renewing it so I have the renewal receipt. I got a job offer in France and now I have to apply for a visa from the French consulate in Italy.

I need to have a valid permit stay in Italy to apply for a visa in Rome. I thought of asking for a temporary permit stay in Italy (permesso di soggiorno provvisorio).

Can I apply for a long-term visa with the temporary permit stay at the French consulate in Rome? Would it make a problem for my visa application?

Comment: ah okay! Thanks for that, I will ask there then

Comment: @CSM the post is written in the knowledge that a separate new visa is needed; the question is how to apply for it.